# Get Values from HashMap and Populate a Java Object

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, hashmap

I have map populated from database Data. 
I need to get values from there to Object.
Field names in POJO and key names in Map object are different. I did it as the below. is there any effective way to do this

```
 Map<String ,Object> map; //retrieved from database

Employee e = new Employee();
if(map!=null) {
    if(map.containsKey("name")) {
        e.setFirstName(map.get("name"));
    }
    if(map.containsKey("ads")) {
        e.setMyAddress(map.get("ads"));
    }
    if(map.containsKey("country")) {
        e.setDealCountry(map.get("country"));
    }
    if(map.containsKey("keyId")) {
        e.Id(map.get("keyId"));
    }
}



public class Employee {
    String firstName;
    String id;
    String myAdreess;
    String dealCountry;
//setter getters
}
```

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but in all likelihood they will not be better than doing it this way.  I’m sure you’ll get at least one reflection-based answer, but reflection would be a terrible way to do it, as it’s prone to errors which will be pretty hard to detect.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your Problem is exactly?! I haven't tested your code but what is the issue? Are you just asking if this is a valid/effective way to do whatever you are doing?

Comment: I understand that you think this is ugly and I would look for alternatives as well. As long as you don't have to do this for countless classes, your approach is fine. Take a look at my answer below for some other magic.

Comment: @MichaelHolley Yes i Need to know whether  there is any efficient way to do this. Because i have to write lot of if conditions for multiple field checking

Comment: Just remove the `if(map.containsKey(…))` checks. If your `Employee` has no meaningful default values for the properties anyway, the worst thing that can happen with `e.setFirstName(map.get("name"));` without a check, is that it sets a `null` property to `null` again. Otherwise, if you have meaningful defaults, just use them, e.g. `e.setFirstName(map.getOrDefault("name", "no name in db stored"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java8+'s BiConsumer to define a setter for each of the map's keys:

```
    Map<String, BiConsumer<Employee, String>> consumerMap = new HashMap<>();
    consumerMap.put("name", Employee::setFirstName);
    consumerMap.put("ads", Employee::setMyAddress);
    consumerMap.put("country", Employee::setDealCountry);
    //and so on

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();//the data from your database 
    Employee e = new Employee();
    if (map != null) {
        consumerMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                //value is the BiConsumer
                value.accept(e, map.get(key));
            }
        });
    }
```

The forEach iterates over all the the defined mappings, then checks if your `Map` from the database has the respective keys and applies the data.

This does not involve any (manual) reflection and the mapping from the map's key to the setter is very direct.

Comment: Or `map.forEach((key,value) -> consumerMap.getOrDefault(key, (x,y)->{}).accept(e, value));`

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to Hibernate or other ORM's. They automatically do the mapping for you.

Here for example a link to the Hibernate ORM: https://hibernate.org/

It's easier and faster than make the mapping manuelly. ;)